# How to import a Three.js loader into an Angular 6 project

Tags: angular, three.js, angular-cli, angular6

I want to extend the type definitions imported into an ng6 project using Three.js (`@types/three/index`) with a set of functions that will be directly attached to the same "namespace". Something like: `THREE.myFunction()`. **I don't want to declare THREE as `any`** to suppress the type checking and the linter, and I guess that it would be possible to wrap a vanilla JS function that extend THREE using a TS class/function and then taking advantage of `typings.d.ts`.

#### Importing a loader

First of all, I would like to import a THREE.js loader into my project, and that's normally defined a vanilla function that extends `THREE`.

I'm trying to import the [`BinaryLoader`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/BinaryLoader.js) into a ng service and I'm not sure about how to do it in the right way.

What I have done so far:

1. `npm install three --save`
2. `npm install @types/three --save-dev`
3. `import * as THREE from 'three';`
4. add the BinaryLoader to the new *angular.json* `scripts` array

*angular.json*

```
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/three/examples/js/loaders/BinaryLoader.js"
        ]
```

So far so good, but now I need to create a binary loader:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
// import { BinaryLoader } from 'three';
// import 'three/examples/js/loaders/BinaryLoader';

export class ThreeManagerService {
   const loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
   ...
```

and I have to find the way to add the `BinaryLoader` to `@types/three/index` somehow. In that way I should be able to **extend the type definitions** in order to be able to create a new type `THREE.BinaryLoader`. Is it possible to do something like that?

The warning I got is:

> WARNING in ./src/app/shared/three-manager.service.ts
>   24:25-43 "export 'BinaryLoader' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in 'three'

### Silencing Type warnings and the TS transpiler

A workaround to get rid of the warnings and the error might be something like that:

```
import * as THREEJS from 'three';
declare const THREE: any;

export class ThreeManagerService {
   const loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
```

the fact is that I consider this workaround a very ugly "fix". I would like to use the type system as much as possible.

### EDIT: Get examples to play nice with Intellisense & Typescript

While waiting for a complete rewriting of the examples to be compatible with the ES6 modules and namespaces it could be possible to define a local module that exposes and augments the global, in `/src/node_modules/three-extras/index.ts`:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

declare global {
   interface Window {
      THREE: typeof THREE;
   }
}

window.THREE = THREE;

require('three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls');
require('three/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader');
```

via: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562#issuecomment-386522819

#### Related and useful SO answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42602169/1977778
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42623509/1977778

Comment: Are you sure BinaryLoader is defined inside three.js file? I don't think so

Comment: @HariV yes, this loader, like many others, is part of the three.js library and it has been defined as an "example". Actually, there's an ongoing discussion about the fact that many scripts defined as simple ES5 scripts haven't been modularised on [this ticket](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562) of the Three.js Github repository.

Comment: After a lot of reading I found [this comment](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562#issuecomment-379112299) particularly useful. Apparently, there's a an ES6-compliant porting of Three.js named [three-full](https://github.com/Itee/three-full). So, it should be possible to use it to load the loaders or controls as modules. Hooray!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've finally reached two working solutions (=> workarounds to be precise).

#### Using Webpack's imports-loader

> [...] [import-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader) is a Webpack plugin allows you to inject a global variable into your module's scope. So the global (`!`) namespace of your execution context still remains completely clean, but during "compilation", Webpack will be able to figure out where to lookup the binding for a module that only comes with a global variable.

Via [this three.js ticket](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562#issuecomment-252506801)

```
import "imports?THREE=three!loaders/BinaryLoader";
```

Using this import we tell Webpack to use `THREE` as a global variable defined by the npm module `'three'` and the BinaryLoader wont be binded to any variable.

#### Use three-full to provide the THREE namespace

The project [three-full](https://github.com/Itee/three-full) extends the namespace defined by the standard three.js library adding several "examples" like loaders and controls. Using it instead of the classical `three` npm package it will be possible to have full support to ES6 namespaces for the most common and useful classes that usually are part of the great majority of those projects based on three.js.

```
npm install --save three-full
```

And then you can import the entire namespace:

```
import * as THREE from 'three-full';
...
const loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
```

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been struggling with this. I looked for answers everywhere! Thank you so much!

Comment: I suspect that @K-Dawg, like myself and I'm sure countless others, expected to be able to use three.js just like most other NPM packages. I'm stunned by my forgetfulness that meshing libraries is complex and fortunately tools like yarn/npm have streamlined that for us. Anyway, thanks for a full answer that provides a range of solution. Many karma upvotes to you.

Answer (score 0):

How using a little helper library, i'm looking to do the same - I found this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-three

Answer (score 0):

Two steps, install the package and then the types.

1. npm install three --save
2. npm install @types/three --save-dev

And then in your component just import is as:
**import * as THREE from 'three';**

You are all set with types and package.